# My attributes are not appending correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

The current code seems to append everything as long as any data-item that is less or equal to 12.

```
<div id="div1">
        <li data-item="11"></li>

        <li data-item="12"></li>

        <li data-item="13"></li>

        <li data-item="14"></li>
</div>

<div id="div2"></div>
```

Is there something missing from the IF Statement?

```
$("#button").on("click", function(){
    var item = $("div li").each(function(){
        return $(this).filter('[data-item]');
    });
    if (item.attr("data-item") <= 12){
        item.appendTo("#div2");
    } 
});
```

Comment: Hmm... What's `x`? Also, if you append `item`, you'll either append all things with `data-item`, or none. You should probably scrap `filter` and move `appendTo` inside the `each`.

Comment: your html is invalid... `li` must be a child of `ul` or `ol`

Comment: @ArunPJohny it seems that this is only part of the code (`.filter`)

Comment: can you please post a fiddle?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/HZcXk/1/

Comment: The fiddle code worked.

http://jsfiddle.net/HZcXk/1/

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your markup is invalid, you should wrap the `li` elements with an `ol` or `ul` element. Also the usage of `.fllter()` method is not correct and `x` variable is `undefined`, try the following:

```
<ul id="ul1">
    <li data-item="11"></li>
    <li data-item="12"></li>
    <li data-item="13"></li>
    <li data-item="14"></li>
</ul>
<ul id="ul2"></ul>
```

```
$("#button").on("click", function() {
    // Filter the li elements
    $("#ul1 li").filter(function(_, item) {
        return $(item).attr("data-item") <= 12;
    }).appendTo("#ul2"); // append the returned elements to another element
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vPXh3/

Answer (score 0):

no the `if` is ok... problem is `x` is undefined.

just write

```
item.appendTo("#div2");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//define x



$("#button").on("click", function(){
    var item = $("div li").each(function(){
    return $(this).filter('[data-item]');
    });
    if (item.attr("data-item") <= 12){
    var  x = //item;
    x.appendTo("#div2");
    } 
    });
```